# Cookies gone after reload Puppeteer => page.setCookie(...cookies)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, puppeteer

I saw some troubles on Github with the `page.setCookie(...cookies)` method.

I was wondering if someone is able to save a cookie persistant with this method. I've already seen workarounds (but thats not my question)

In this code I simple set a cookie and then reload the page. With reloading the page the cookie is not there anymore. I tried to remove expires, set it to 0, 1, -1 or to a Unix timestamp in the future.... Didnt work

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const OPT = {
    headless: false,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--user-data-dir']
};

const COOKS =
    [ { name: 'tdsess',
        value: 'TEST_DRIVE_SESSION',
        domain: 'testing-ground.scraping.pro',
        path: '/',
        expires: -1,
        size: 24,
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: false,
        session: true } ];

(async () => {
    const URL = `http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login`
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(OPT)
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(URL, { 'waitUntil' : 'networkidle2' })

    await page.setCookie(...COOKS)
    let cook = await page.cookies()

    console.log(`==== first login ====`)
    console.log(cook)
    console.log(`==================`)

    await page.reload()
    console.log(`after reload`)
    setInterval(async () => {
        cook = await page.cookies()
        console.log(cook)
    }, 3000)
})()
```

This will output:

```
==== first login ====
[ { name: 'tdsess',
    value: 'TEST_DRIVE_SESSION',
    domain: 'testing-ground.scraping.pro',
    path: '/',
    expires: -1,
    size: 24,
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false,
    session: true } ]
==================
after reload
[]
[]
```

Versions I used:

*** Puppeteer 1.7.0 * Nodejs 10.8.0 ***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not visit the correct URL for the login page

`http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login?mode=welcome`

After visiting this page it looks good.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const OPT = {
    headless: false,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--user-data-dir']
};

const COOKS =
    [ { name: 'tdsess',
        value: 'TEST_DRIVE_SESSION',
        domain: 'testing-ground.scraping.pro',
        path: '/',
        expires: -1,
        size: 24,
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: false,
        session: true } ];

(async () => {
    const URL = `http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login?mode=welcome`
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(OPT)
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setCookie(...COOKS)
    await page.goto(URL, { 'waitUntil' : 'networkidle2' })


    let cook = await page.cookies()

    console.log(`==== first login ====`)
    console.log(cook)
    console.log(`==================`)

    await page.reload()
    console.log(`after reload`)
    setInterval(async () => {
        cook = await page.cookies()
        console.log(cook)
    }, 3000)
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for this question is hidden in `path: '/'` inside cookie settings.

If you set it to `path: '/login'` (since you are trying to register it on `http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login` route) it should register correctly and be available on repeat visits.